# Error in sending decimal in HTTP GET parameter from a JSP

Tags: java, http, jsp, liferay, portlet

In my program i am sending quantity as a parameter from one portlet to the controller via HTTP GET.
If there is a decimal value in the parameter, there is error.
Below is the code :

```
var link = '<%=themeDisplay.getPortalURL()%>' + '<%=ConfigUtil.getConfigValue("PRINT_PAGE")%>?type=' + type + '&contentId=' + id + '&quantity=' + quantity ;

window.open(link, '', "directories=0,height=480,left=80,location=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,status=0,toolbar=0,top=180,width=760");
```

The code does not hit the server, and the error which i get is

```
2012-04-20 17:06:17,094 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor] Forward does not exist
```

Comment: If quantity has an "." as decimal separator, then it should work...

Comment: Whats the error you get? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: If the value sent in quantity is 3.5, it fails

Comment: What about quantity 3%2E5 ? Which error do you get?

Comment: even encodeURI or encodeURIComponent doesnt seem to be working.The request does not hit the server, the address bar shows correct URL ocalhost:8080/web/guest/print?type=RECIPE&contentId=205&quantity=7.8